# Titanium.Network.online returning true when connected to Wifi that has no internet connection

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

In the app I am developing we are trying to figure out if the internet connection dies and show an error screen. 
We tried using the Titanium.Network.online parameter and the Titanium.Network change event, but those only work in some cases. We found out that if the router loses connectivity, but the phone is still connected to the WiFi, the Titanium.Network.online parameter will return true and not false.

After a short search, I even found that this is a bug in Titanium and there's a bug report that is unresolved from 2013: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIDOC-1151

So my questions are:

Has anybody found a workaround for this?

Is there another way of getting an event when there is a loss of connection? (Besides the obvious ping a server every 5 or 10 seconds)

Any Support guys from Appcelerator can tell us if the issue will ever be  resolved?

Comment: I'm also interesting on that. Let me know if you find something.
The current solution for that is this module:
https://github.com/benbahrenburg/Pinger
But it does sort of what you described =/

Comment: I think without pinging its a bit hard to tell if you have internet because you are connected to a network (wifi) so you have an IP and are online in your local network. It gets even more complicated if you have a WIFI with a captive-portal because it will return http requests (but with a different page, not your e.g. API). networkTypeName and networkType could help, so you can at least tell if you are on mobile, but if its WIFI you have the same as before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree the property name can be confusing. It should be `connected` since that is all we can tell.

I don't think there's a good way to determine if you really are "online". You could do a HTTP request to a site that is likely to be up, but that's a hack.

Comment: You could do a feature request to rename the property. Please check if it has already been requested at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it has not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide a complete description in the ticket. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.